# Right justify FB like button in wordpress header

Tags: css, wordpress, facebook-like

I'm trying to right-justify an element in my WP header but its not working =/

My twitter follow button is shifting right, what can I be doing wrong?

Thanks!

[image: a busy cat]

code: http://pastebin.com/0rhiUqrf

Comment: Dear see my answer and let me know if i am lagging some where.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

see the fiddle for code and demo

fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jXkU5/

demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/jXkU5/embedded/result/

SS:

[image]